# Compare two databases and find common value in a row

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, mysql-python

I have two databases (infact two database dump  ... db1.sql and db2.sql)

both database have only 1 table in each.

in each table there are few columns (not equal number nor type) but 1 or 2 columns have same type and same value

i just want to go through both databases and find a row from each table so that they both have one common value

now from these two rows(one from each table) i would extract some information and would write into a file.

I want efficient methods to do that

PS: If you got my question please edit the title

EDIT: I want to compare these two tables(database) by a column which have contact number as primary key.
but the problem is one table has it is as an integer(big integer) and other table has it is as a string. now how could i inner-join them.
basically i dont want to create another database, i simply want to store two columns from each table into a file so I guess i dont need inner-join. do i?

e.g.

in table-1 = 9876543210

in table-2 = "9876543210"

Answer (score 0):

You can use Join with alias name.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand what it is you want to do. You want to match a value from a column from one table to a value from a column from another table?

If you'd have the data in two tables in a database, you could make an inner join.
Depending on how big the file is, you could use a manual comparison tool like WinMerge.

Comment: yes you understood my question.
now plz suggest best method to do in ubuntu.